# Automatically Delete Temporary Files using "new" Java File API

Tags: java, temporary-files

After years of coding with the old `File` API, I'm finally ready to hop onto the whole `Path`/`Paths` train. For the most part, this has gone smoothly, however, I'm stumped on this particular aspect: temporary files.

The documentation on [`java.nio.Files#createTempFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) says:

> As with the `File.createTempFile` methods, this method is only part of a temporary-file facility. Where used as a work files, the resulting file may be opened using the `DELETE_ON_CLOSE` option so that the file is deleted when the appropriate close method is invoked. Alternatively, a shutdown-hook, or the `File.deleteOnExit()` mechanism may be used to delete the file automatically.

I don't see where the `DELETE_ON_CLOSE` option is supposed to be specified. Using a shutdown hook is incredibly inconvenient (unless I'm thinking of it wrong). In an effort to avoid using both `Path` objects *and* `File` objects, I am looking for a solution similar to the `File.deleteOnExit()` for the Path object, but obviously one that doesn't require using `Path.toFile().[...].toPath()` sort of calling pattern.

**What is the correct way to implement "self-destructing" temporary files using the `java.nio.Files` API?**

Comment: `path.toFile().deleteOnExit()` ?

Comment: @assylias I had thought of this, but I thought there would be a better way of doing it. The `toFile()` method converts to a `File` object, which is part of the old API. This is the solution I'm using now, but like I said, I'm trying to avoid using the old API.

Comment: File is not deprecated and there is nothing wrong with that solution! To use the open option you can, for example, use one of the Files.newXxx, such as newBufferedWriter. But that may not be practical for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

You set that option when you write, for example:

```
Path myTempFile = Files.createTempFile(...);
Files.write(myTempFile, ..., StandardOpenOption.DELETE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: While technically correct, you code example is quite useless as written, since it deletes the temp file immediately after writing to it. That said, the `Files` class also provides several methods for which the `DELETE_ON_CLOSE` option actually makes sense, such as [`newByteChannel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newByteChannel-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-).